# Which option is correct?

Tags: articles

Can you tell which option is correct? And why it is necessary to use or not to use this or that article?

> I have pizza.

or

> I have a pizza.

Comment: oh, I accidentally clicked on " Blockquote"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are actually both correct.
I will list two scenarios, one for each one, to show how they are correct.

1.

```
Bob: I'm so hungry! Does anyone have food?
Bobby: I have pizza.
```

2.

```
Bob: Finally, it's lunch time. Guess what I have?
Bobby: I don't know, what do you have? A sandwich?
Bob: I have a pizza!
Bobby: Ooh lucky!
```

As you can see, they both make sense in each scenario, and if you put on in the other scenario, they will still work. It's a matter of what you mean. `I have a pizza` means that you have one pizza. `I have pizza` means you have pizza. One is more specific than the other.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! If plural, will the articles be omitted? Right?

Comment: Many foodstuffs, even things which come in discrete pieces, can be used as non-count nouns: chicken, cake, garlic.

Comment: @Sweet_Cherry No, it doesn't. *I have pizza* does *not* mean *I have more than one pizza.* Only *I have* ***pizzas*** means a plural. *Pizza*, without an article, doesn't specify a number.

Comment: @JasonBassford Oop. I stand corrected. I guess I was focusing more on either plural or singular.